# PHP foreach loop show data but no duplicate value

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I need to show data using foreach loop but no duplicate value in first 10 values, and then no duplicate values in second 10 values and continue the process. Please help me with the logic and code. Here is the code:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_custom_form ORDER BY ID desc;");
    //print_r($results);

    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    // echo "<th>Email</th>";
    echo "<th>Website</th>";
    echo "<th>City</th>";
    echo "<th>Comment</th>";

    foreach($results as $result){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$result->Name."</td>";
    // echo "<td>".$result->Email."</td>";
    echo "<td><a target='blank' href='http://$result->Website'>".$result->Website."</a></td>";
    echo "<td>".$result->City."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$result->Comment."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Please give us some code so we can help you. Show us what you ave tried, and what is your input array, and the expected results. This way we can help you faster and with a more accurate answer. Already my comment have more content that your question. :/

Comment: @Imran H.  This question requires a sample array (preferrably greater than 20 elements), explanation of the issue and what you've attempted.  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @chris85
Can you please give me some code so that i can understand better ?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: @chris85 
Yes, no duplicates, or if a value was in the first 10 it can be in the second 10 but only once

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks Mick !

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier Thanks !

Comment: @ImranH. Your question is still unclear. What are you using to identify uniqueness?  Name?  What do you want to do when a duplicate is found? omit it entirely? or bump it down to the next batch of 10?

Comment: @ImranH. Rough example posted.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier 
Please check the answer of chris85. No, it's $results->Website. I want to  not echo if duplicate is found.

Comment: There was an answer. Why can't i see that ?

Comment: @ImranH. chris855 tried to offer a working solution, but you still have us all making too many assumptions about how to handle the duplicates.  Please edit your question to include the output (at least 20 rows) of `echo "<pre>";
var_export($results);
echo "</pre>";`.  And write out how you wish to display it -- show us the 10 values in the first group (no duplicates) then the 10 values in the second group (no duplicates).  After you do this, you can @ping us with a comment.

Comment: Can you please tell me, there was an answer, why can't i see that ?

Comment: @ImranH.  As I said in my previous comment, chris855 offered an answer but there could be no confidence with its accuracy/success until you provide more information about your results data.  We want to help you, but first you must provide all relevant information.  Please edit your question to include the $results array data.